# Facebook C# SDK - invite friend to Web SIte

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a web site and I want to give a opportunity to users to invite their facebook friends to this web site.

I have:

1. C# Facebook SDK installed to project
2. Facebook Dev Account with new app

Users at my site use site's auth control (not oAuth). They register on site and can connect their Facebook profile.

The question is next one: How to allow users to invite their friends to web site not using facebook oAuth (just sending user id) with Facebook C# SDK (or without if it's not possible in this way)

**UPDATED**

I want to do this in next way: user click the button "invite friends" (standart invitation screen of FB), check friend, click invite - finish action :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at the Requests dialog here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Only drawback is, that when users accept the request, they'll be shown your Canvas URL - which means this page loads inside the Facebook UI - they're not redirected to you site entirely.

You could use this page to "sell" your website, so they navigate to your site.

Another approach is using the new Send button: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

This will send a message with a link to your site.

Comment: ok, i will try this. tell me please, do you know an exapmles of using standart auth and openId?

Comment: Are we talking Graph API Authentication now? Then OAuth is the only way. If you want your users to sign into your website using Facebook (what I think was called Facebook Connect until just recently), then you should use the JavaScript SDK: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that is possible. Becuase to access user private data  you need to authenticate yourself as well as user with facebook. Facebook provides OAuth for the same !

Comment: thanks for unswer! I think it's possible in next way - send user id, check if user iser is auth on facebook, if yes get acsess token